# Stern-brocot rational numbers not omitted proof

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

I am self-teaching myself through the Concrete Mathematics book, and recently saw the proof for (no rational numbers are omitted in stern brocot tree construction) as mentioned in link below :

[proof text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVPhg.png)

The part that I have trouble understanding is the line above to below with "imply that",

I believe $\frac{a}{b} - \frac{m}{n} \gt 0$
should lead to 
$an - bm > 0$

but why/how does it imply in the proof

that
$an - bm \ge 1$ ?

Comment: In integers $\,a \gt b \iff a \ge b+1\,$.

Comment: The fact that there is no integer strictly between $0$ and $1$ (so that $>0$ implies $\ge 1$) is obvious once you use it a couple times, but is a surprisingly powerful tool that shows up in a lot of proofs.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to make sense, wasn't aware of this property, Thanks. If you would like to add it as answer, I will mark it as complete and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint (expanding on the previously posted comment):  in integers $a \gt b \iff a \ge b+1\,$.

The above is equivalent to $n \gt 0 \iff n \ge 1$ which follows from the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle). The set $X = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n \gt 0\}$ must contain a [least element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element). Since $0 \not\in X$ and its successor $1 \in X$ it follows that the least element is $1\,$, therefore $n \ge 1\,$. (*If this argument is not satisfactory then you'll need to specify the particular formalism/construction of integers that you are working with.*)